# How do I get the high- and low-order bits of a SHORT?

Tags: c++, winapi, short

The function [GetKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a SHORT that contains the key's state (up/down in the high-order bit, and toggled in the low-order). How do I get those values?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple bit manipulation will work. SHORTs are 16-bit integers, so to get the low- and high-order bits you can do the following:

```
lowBit = value & 1;
highBit = ((unsigned short) value) >> 15;
```

Also, note that the LOBYTE and HIBYTE macros are used to break SHORTs into low- and high-order *bytes*, not to test individual bits in a byte.

Comment: It is more common to AND with `0x8000` instead of bitshifting.

Answer (score 12):

That's not how you use the return value of GetKeyState().  Do it like this instead:

```
SHORT state = GetKeyState(VK_INSERT);
bool down = state < 0;
bool toggle = (state & 1) != 0;
```

Comment: thanks hans, but that was an example i just wanted to know how to get the low and high bits of a short

Comment: value & 0xff* you want bitwise, not logic

Answer (score 4):

The normal way to check the result of `GetKeyState` or `GetAsyncKeyState` is bitwise-and with `0x8000` (binary `1000 0000 0000 0000`).

```
#define IS_DOWN( GetKeyState(x) & 0x8000 )
if( IS_DOWN( VK_ESCAPE ) ) // escape is down.
```

Answer (score 3):

If Google brought you here like it did me while trying to find information on `GetKeyboardState()` instead of `GetKeyState()`, note that it acts on an array of **BYTE**, not **SHORT**.

- If you choose to bitwise `AND`, you should use `0x80`, not `0x8000`.
- If you shift, use `>> 7`, not `>> 15`.

For example, to determine if either CTRL keys are down:

```
BYTE keyboardState[256];
GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
if (keyboardState[VK_CONTROL] & 0x80)
{
    std::cout << "control key!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define LOBYTE(a) ((CHAR)(a))
#define HIBYTE(a) ((CHAR)(((WORD)(a) >> 8) & 0xFF))
```

Comment: do you mean LOSHORT and HISHORT instead of LOBYTE and HIBYTE because those two are already defined in 'Windows.h'

Comment: I think what Dylan is looking for is ChrisV's answer, since the GetKeyState() documentation states that "If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.". For me that means "the most significant bit". Dylan, basically the LOSHORT/HISHORT macros and the shifting/masking for GetKeyState() are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

WORD == SHORT, HIWORD works on DWORDs, HIBYTE works on SHORTs/WORDs.

Comment: WORD != SHORT. WORD == *unsigned* SHORT. For a beginner, there's no reason to assume that HIBYTE, which is documented to accept a WORD, would also accept some other type. It's also not clear whether the result would still be unsigned even though the argument wasn't.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter because the OP wasn't interested in bytes anyway... Still I think knowing WORD == SHORT is better than not knowing anything about the relation between the two :)

Answer (score 0):

`GetKeyState` currently returns `SHORT` datatype, which typedef from `short`.
`short` resides within range `–32,768 to 32,767`. One approach to detect highest enabled bit (key is down) is make it unsigned and then to query against `0x8000` const value.

Another approach is to keep value as signed and simply compare it against 0.

```
bool bIsKeyDown = GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0;
```

Like it's mentioned in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789914/2338477

all negative values have highest bit enabled, as all positive values and zero have highest bit disabled.

This is example table for char, but same is applicable to short data type as well, only table will be slightly larger.

```
bits  value
0000    0
0001    1
0010    2
0011    3
0100    4
0101    5
0110    6
0111    7
1000   -8
1001   -7
1010   -6
1011   -5
1100   -4
1101   -3
1110   -2
1111   -1
```

And key toggling can be checked using normal "and" operation, like mentioned by other answers here:

```
bool bIsKeyToggled = GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 1;
```