# What is the difference between signed and unsigned int

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

What is the difference between signed and unsigned int?

Comment: This is a real question, and the answer is not so simple but rather subtle.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  It might be a duplicate, but it's definitely a real question.

Comment: Re: "It might be a duplicate" - [What is a difference between unsigned int and signed int in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812022/what-is-a-difference-between-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-in-c)

Comment: More tags should be added, since many languages use them.

Comment: This question may need a chapter to elaborate. If you want to know the ins and outs, check [Unsigned and Signed Integers](http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/13.html) for more explanation.

Answer (score 202):

As you are probably aware, `int`s are stored internally in binary.  Typically an `int` contains 32 bits, but in some environments might contain 16 or 64 bits (or even a different number, usually but not necessarily a power of two).

But for this example, let's look at 4-bit integers.  Tiny, but useful for illustration purposes.

Since there are four bits in such an integer, it can assume one of 16 values; 16 is two to the fourth power, or 2 times 2 times 2 times 2.  What are those values?  The answer depends on whether this integer is a `signed int` or an `unsigned int`.  With an `unsigned int`, the value is never negative; there is no sign associated with the value.  Here are the 16 possible values of a four-bit `unsigned int`:

```
bits  value
0000    0
0001    1
0010    2
0011    3
0100    4
0101    5
0110    6
0111    7
1000    8
1001    9
1010   10
1011   11
1100   12
1101   13
1110   14
1111   15
```

... and Here are the 16 possible values of a four-bit `signed int`:

```
bits  value
0000    0
0001    1
0010    2
0011    3
0100    4
0101    5
0110    6
0111    7
1000   -8
1001   -7
1010   -6
1011   -5
1100   -4
1101   -3
1110   -2
1111   -1
```

As you can see, for `signed int`s the most significant bit is `1` if and only if the number is negative.  That is why, for `signed int`s, this bit is known as the "sign bit".

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out is that this is the two's complement format, which admittedly is nowadays widely used. There are also other ways to represent signed integers, most notably one's complement.

Comment: Correct.  And the ISO9899 C standard does not even require that either one's complement or two's complement be used; any other convention that actually works is permissible.

Comment: Although two's complement is not required, `(unsigned)(-1)` is required to be the maximum representable value for `unsigned` (independent of the binary representation), which is trivially true for 2's complement, but not other representations.

Comment: @BillEvansatMariposa: The standard says that for signed integers there're 3 allowed representations: sign+magnitude, 2's complement, 1's complement. Any other would have to be invisible to the program and be perceived as one of these 3.

Comment: Ok but under the hood! What is REALLY happening! What is the difference between a SIGNED and UNSIGNED number! How does the machine manage the computation? It just subtracts a value from the another? How it differences 1111 = 15 and 1111 = -1 ?

Comment: @Mihail Georgescu: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Unsigned 1111 - 0001 = 1110: 15 - 1 = 14.  Signed 1111 - 0001 = 1110: -1 - 1 = -2.  Addition and subtraction work the same whether signed or unsigned. If the machine has both signed and unsigned integer overflow detection, then of course those would work differently from each other.

Comment: @BillEvansatMariposa no sir! I didn't know how signed and unsigned actually work. Yesterday I found out that whatever the yield of the instruction is the answer is INTERPRETED by the language itself in case of negative numbers using TWO's complement. That's what confused me, didn't knew how the CPU can make the difference but he doesn't actually make any difference. Thank you for you answer! I salute you.

Comment: The difference between signed and unsigned integers is not just implemented in the language; it has support in the CPU itself. If you add two integers, you can check for overflow with one CPU flag (or set of flags) for unsigned, and with another CPU flag (or set of flags) for signed.  Similarly, if you are comparing two numbers, you can check the result with one CPU flag (or set of flags) for unsigned, and with another CPU flag (or set of flags) for signed.

Answer (score 94):

In laymen's terms an unsigned int is an integer that can not be negative and thus has a higher range of positive values that it can assume. A signed int is an integer that can be negative but has a lower positive range in exchange for more negative values it can assume.

Comment: Sometimes simple answers like this go a long way explaining this.

Comment: Best explanation in simple terms!

Comment: Note that it is not guaranteed that an unsigned integer has a higher range of positive values. The standard only guarantees that all non-negative values of the signed type can be stored in the corresponding unsigned type.

Answer (score 28):

`int` and `unsigned int` are two distinct integer types. (`int` can also be referred to as `signed int`, or just `signed`; `unsigned int` can also be referred to as `unsigned`.)

As the names imply, `int` is a *signed* integer type, and `unsigned int` is an *unsigned* integer type. That means that `int` is able to represent negative values, and `unsigned int` can represent only non-negative values.

The C language imposes some requirements on the ranges of these types. The range of `int` must be at least `-32767` .. `+32767`, and the range of `unsigned int` must be at least `0` .. `65535`. This implies that both types must be at least 16 bits. They're 32 bits on many systems, or even 64 bits on some. `int` typically has an extra negative value due to the two's-complement representation used by most modern systems.

Perhaps the most important difference is the behavior of signed vs. unsigned arithmetic. For signed `int`, overflow has undefined behavior. For `unsigned int`, there is no overflow; any operation that yields a value outside the range of the type wraps around, so for example `UINT_MAX + 1U == 0U`.

Any integer type, either signed or unsigned, models a subrange of the infinite set of mathematical integers. As long as you're working with values within the range of a type, everything works.  When you approach the lower or upper bound of a type, you encounter a discontinuity, and you can get unexpected results. For signed integer types, the problems occur only for very large negative and positive values, exceeding `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`. For unsigned integer types, problems occur for very large positive values **and at zero**. This can be a source of bugs. For example, this is an infinite loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 10; i >= 0; i --) {
    printf("%u\n", i);
}
```

because `i` is *always* greater than or equal to zero; that's the nature of unsigned types. (Inside the loop, when `i` is zero, `i--` sets its value to `UINT_MAX`.)

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes we know in advance that the value stored in a given integer variable will always be positive-when it is being used to only count things, for example. In such a case we can declare the variable to be unsigned, as in, `unsigned int num student;`. With such a declaration, the range of permissible integer values (for a 32-bit compiler) will shift from the range -2147483648 to +2147483647 to range 0 to 4294967295. Thus, declaring an integer as unsigned almost doubles the size of the largest possible value that it can otherwise hold.

Comment: @Alex I was in the middle of editing that answer 10mins ago and it's identical. lol

Answer (score -2):

In practice, there are two differences:

1. **printing** (eg with `cout` in C++ or `printf` in C): unsigned integer bit representation is interpreted as a nonnegative integer by print functions.
2. **ordering**: the ordering depends on signed or unsigned specifications.

this code can identify the integer using ordering criterion:

```
char a = 0;
a--;
if (0 < a)
    printf("unsigned");
else
    printf("signed");
```

`char` is considered `signed` in some compilers and `unsigned` in other compilers. The code above determines which one is considered in a compiler, using the ordering criterion. If `a` is unsigned, after `a--`, it will be greater than `0`, but if it is `signed` it will be less than zero. But in both cases, the bit representation of `a` is the same. That is, in both cases `a--` does the same change to the bit representation.

Comment: If this explained the different with one dealing in negative numbers and the other, not. It would help this post a lot.

Comment: @DanielJackson Unclear what you say. a char can be considered negative or positive depending on compiler. the output of the code depends on what compiler chooses and this  shows the difference between signed and unsigned.