# Reversing the bits of an integer in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to reverse the bits of an integer in the C program. Even though I have looked at [the same question by another user](/q/9144800), I was unable to understand most of the code that was written. I have noticed that the code I have is similar to 
[the answer by Eregrith](/a/9144875) but I cannot identify the problem with my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int num)
{
unsigned int reverse_num = 0; /* initialize the result*/
unsigned int count = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8 - 1; /* counter to track the number of bits in the integer*/

while (num != 0)
{
    unsigned int last_bit = num & 1; /* get the right-most bit*/
    reverse_num = reverse_num | last_bit; /* add that bit to the right-most bit of the desired reversed bits*/
    reverse_num = reverse_num << 1; /* shift the reversed bits left*/
    num = num >> 1; /* shift the original bits right*/
    count--;
}
reverse_num = reverse_num << count; /* If the original bits have only 0
s then shift the remaining bits left*/

return reverse_num;
}

int main()
{

reverse_bits(1);
}
```

If I enter `reverse_bits(1)`, the code returns -2147483648, which clearly did not reverse the bits of the integer 1. I am new to code and I am having difficulty locating the source of this error. Without having to change the entire code, how can I modify my existing code to return the correct output?

Comment: There is a difference between [integer and unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5739888/1865106).  Also, if you use [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) to print your result, you want to use `%d` for integer and `%u` for unsigned integer.

Comment: How did you see that `-2147483648` that you are mentioning? You are using `unsigned int`, you shouldn't see any negative number, unless you are mixing `int` and `unsigned int` by mistake, which I don't see anywhere in your code.

Comment: How do you conclude the result was -2147483648 ? All your code does is invoke the `reverse_bits` function. Where is the code that generated your output on which you base your conclusion?

Comment: "which is clearly did not reverse the bits of the integer 1".  If you don't like what you get, you should always tell us what you expect to get and why.

Comment: Where does the magic constant `8` come from?  Did you mean `CHAR_BIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't provide the part of code that does the printing, it is somehow obvious that you are mixing `int` and `unsigned int`.

For `printf()` function family the specifier for `unsigned int` is `%u` so if you want to print your output, you should use:

```
printf("%u\n", reverse_bits(1));
```

Other than that your code is OK and besides, note that if a machine uses 2's complement and 32 bits for an int, `-2147483648 = 10000000000000000000000000000000` which is a bit reversal of `1 = 00000000000000000000000000000001`.

Comment: 1. By mixing `int` and `unsigned int`, do you mean that I am using `unsigned int` when I should be using `int`?

2. So, after replacing `reverse_bits(1);` with `printf("%u\n", reverse_bits(1));`, I receive
`2147483648

Process returned 11 (0xB)`

So, the negative sign changed to a positive sign, but it says the process returned 11, which I find strange.

3. Is there any way for me to request that the machine print out `10000000000000000000000000000000` instead of `-2147483648`?

Comment: put %X instead of %u in printf. you will get better clarity. printf("%X\n", reverse_bits(1));

Comment: 1. You should be using `unsigned int`. I was referring to the way you get your output. How did you get the output before I suggest to add `printf()`? 2. That's possibly because your `main()` function doesn't return anything. Add `return 0;` to the end of main. And yes, a bit reversal of `1` should return `2 ^ 31 = 2147483648`. 3. write a function to convert from decimal to binary. That is trivial. If you are developing under Win32/Win64, MS provides a non-standard function `itoa()` that can do that for you but I recommend against using it.

Answer (score 2):

How do you observed that it returns a negative value? `unsigned int`s only are used in your code... I supposed that you tried to print the returned value as an `int` with `%d`, but that is undefined behavior. To print an unsigned you must use `%u` or `%x`.

But your reversal is wrong. You shift the result after adding the last bit, which should be the converse. You also miss the count of bits in an unsigned int (less by one). The following should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int num) {
  unsigned int reverse_num = 0; /* initialize the result*/
  unsigned int count = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; /* counter to track the number of bits in the integer*/

  while (num != 0) {
      unsigned int last_bit = num & 1; /* get the right-most bit*/
      reverse_num <<= 1; /* add one place for the next bit */
      reverse_num |= last_bit; /* add that bit to the right-most bit of the desired reversed bits*/
      num >>= 1; /* remove one bit from the original */
      count--;
    }
  reverse_num <<= count; /* If the original bits have only 0 s then shift the remaining bits left*/
  return reverse_num;
}

int main() {
  printf("%08x\n",reverse_bits(1));
  printf("%08x\n",reverse_bits(3));
  printf("%08x\n",reverse_bits(0x0F0FFFFF));
}
```

---- EDIT ----

As comments mentioned the possible? UB in the case of `num` begin null, I suggest to add a test to eliminate that problem:

```
  if (count!=sizeof(reverse_num)) {
      reverse_num <<= count; /* If the original bits have only 0 s then shift the remaining bits left*/
  } else {
      reverse_num = 0;
  }
  return reverse_num;
```

Comment: With an input of 0, you do `reverse_num <<= sizeof(unsigned int) * 8` which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulHankin Wrong, **6.5.7** The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type.

Comment: You have to read to the end of the standard to J.2, and look at the list of undefined behaviors. One bullet is: "An expression is shifted by a negative number or by an amount greater than or equal
to the width of the promoted expression (6.5.7)". Here, `sizeof(unsigned int)*8` is the width of the promoted expression (assuming 8 bit bytes), so the shift is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulHankin is right. You are relying on undefined behavior for the case of `0`. Because that requires a left shift equal to bit width of `int` which is undefined behavior but then again for `0` you can just return without doing anything.

Comment: My reading is that 6.5.7/4 explicitly refers to undefined behaviour in the case of signed, so J.2 refers to that case, not the case of unsigned. Need language lawyer here? At least a test against 0 is more secure as @m0h4mm4d suggested.

Comment: Standard mentions *"If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width in bits of the promoted left operand. the behavior is undefined."* since our left operand is `unsigned int` promotion is not performed and *the width in bits of promoted left operand* is equal to *the width in bits of left operand*. And it is **6.3.7** in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 :D

Comment: @m0h4mm4d standards are often ambiguous, not clear and subject to interpretation...

Comment: Fair enough. But I don't agree with you in this particular case. I think they were clear about this point.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly to your comments, thanks all.

Comment: Isn't that new piece of code too much? I'd say just `if(num == 0) return 0;` at the top of function is better.

Comment: I disagree, test should be explicit to eliminate UB.