# Fill an array with fread()

Tags: c, arrays, audio, fread

I've just started programming in C. 
I'm trying to write a code able to analyse the values from a wav audio file and write them into the array `buf[num_samples]`; `num_samples` is defined by reading the info contained in the header of the audio file (it is defined as a `uint32_t` variable because the audio file can consist of a huge amount of samples). I found this piece of code:

```
uint16_t buf[num_samples];

// Open WAV file with FFmpeg and read raw samples via the pipe.
FILE *pipe = popen("ffmpeg -i 45s.wav -f s16le -ac 1 -", "r");

// check on the pipe work
if ((pipe = popen("ffmpeg -i 45s.wav -f s16le -ac 1 -", "r"))==NULL) {
    perror("ERROR\n");
}

fread(buf, 2, num_samples, pipe);
pclose(pipe);
```

Where the second argument of `fread()` is 2 (referring to bytes) because I'm using a recorder which works with the parameter `Bit_per_sample = 16`.

However there are problems, in fact the array is filled with "illogical values": I expect values representing a waveform (more or less they should belong to the interval `[-20,000; 32,767]`).
In order to verify the correct filling of the array I have added a printf with `%d` of `buf[i]` in a cicle from `i=0` to `i=num_samples-1`. Below some of the values I got from the output:

> ```
> 64947    65002    65046    65080    65110    65150    65188    65236  
> 65264    65306    65338    65378    65434    65472    65517    8    
> 81       128      168      206      241      268      306      322    
> 424      458      497      520      543      566      586      622       
> 676      699      728      745      765      796      825      840    
> 917      950      970      996      1018     1040     1064     1072 
> 1106     1128
> ```

Can anybody help me or give me some useful advises?
Thank you in advance, hoping I didn't waste your time.

Comment: Could be a byte order issue. Btw you are calling `popen()` twice. Also a 16bit signed integer cannot reach 35,000...

Comment: Could also be a wrong format specifier problem. What is the exact array declaration and how do you print?

Comment: You can find the exact array declaration in the question, it is an int array, containing num_samples positions. I print it with the following code: uint32_t i;

           for (i=0; i<numcampioni; i++) {
            printf("%d    ", buf[i]);
           }

Comment: Try declaring the `buf` array to be `int16_t`.

Comment: Why you are using `popen()` 2 times? Also you have to read starting at the right position.

Comment: Did you read the specs? http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: Very sorry, I made a mistake when I wrote the code in the question: the array buf[num_samples] is already declared as a uint16_t, but the problem, stays. Now I'm going to correct the question. Anyway could you explain me why I'm using popen() twice? Do you mean in the check I wrote in the 'if'?

Comment: @NiccolòCirone: Yes you use it before the check and in the check. Because you are doing it before the if statement you just need `if (pipe == NULL)` or doing the assignment inside of the if and not before. Further to print your values the right way cast them in your printf:  `printf("%d ", (int)buf[i]);`

Comment: Do you understand what `u` in `uint16_t` means? It means unsigned. It means that you will not ever see a negative value in such a variable!

Comment: Furthermore, despite us helping you ages ago, you seem to be not reading *any* comments left to your questions, including the ones asking why the `popen` is being called twice in a question [that has now been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775690/segmentation-fault-caused-by-popen), so you indeed **are** wasting our time.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thank you a lot for your answer, it was not clear to me. Anyway can you explain me the reason why these values have totally no relation with a waveform? Even without a sign I expect to see a local wave behaviour of data, isn't it?

Comment: **You're reading signed 2's complement numbers as unsigned numbers. The waveform is there, you're just not seeing it, because the signed to unsigned conversion.**, thus -1 becomes 65535, -10 => 65525.Change the type to **`int16_t`** as suggested by Paul originally! Notice the lack of `u` in there. It is `int16_t`.

Comment: Also reading this: [Signed to unsigned conversion in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632/8051589) would help because that's what happens! Don't ignore what was said here. The answer is already here, read carefully.

Comment: Finally of the various answers to the question that I linked, please read [this one especially carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789914/918959)

Comment: NiccolòCirone, "more or less they should belong to the interval [-20000; 35000]" is a problem for 2-byte values,  how about a more limited range, only up to 32,767?

Comment: @chux Yes, of course the maximum value is 32767, I've been inaccurate! Thank you for the correction

Comment: You can use sizeof() function to compute the amount of bytes that the function fread will read.

Answer (score 1):

Your type is wrong, You're using `uint16_t` as unsigned type and expect signed values between `[-20,000; 32,767]`.

Declare buf as `int16_t buf[num_samples];` so the buffer is declared as elements of 2 (signed) bytes.

Also, to open and check the pipe use

```
FILE *pipe;
if ((pipe = popen("ffmpeg -i 45s.wav -f s16le -ac 1 -", "r"))==NULL) {
    perror("ERROR\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: `perror` doesn't exit, so one needs to add exit too :)