# What decides an integral type is singed or or unsigned by default?

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned, signed

> Except for `bool` and the extended character types, the integral types
>   **may be** signed or unsigned (34 pp. ***C++ Primer*** 5ed)

**"may be"**, makes me confused, however, please don't give such [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31142149/3004698), I'm not asking the difference between, for example, `int` and `unsigned int` when you explicitly write them down in the declaration. I would like to know for type `char, short, int, long, long long` under what condition it is singed or unsigned

I've write a simple test code on my Mac and compiled by GNU compiler, it tells, the `char` is singed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int minChar = numeric_limits<char>::min(); 
    int maxChar = numeric_limits<char>::max(); 


    cout << minChar << endl; // prints -128
    cout << maxChar << endl; // prints 127
    return 0;
}
```

The same mechanism was applied to all of the sign-able integral types, and the results are shown below.

```
minOfChar: -128
maxOfChar: 127
minOfShort: -32768
maxOfShort: 32767
minOfInt: -2147483648
maxOfInt: 2147483647
minOfLong: 0    // This is interesting, 0
maxOfLong: -1   // and -1  :p
minOfLongLong: 0 // shouldn't use int to hold max/min of long/long long #Bathsheba answered below
maxOfLongLong: -1 // I'll live this error unfixed, that's a stupid pitiful for newbies like me, also good for leaning :)
```

The result tells me, for `char, short, int, long, long long` which is compiled by g++ on a Mac, are singed integers by default.

So the **question** is as the title says:

What decides an integral type is singed or unsigned

Comment: It is only `char` that is unsigned on some systems, because that might work the best on the underlying hardware. Goes all the way back to C ports from the 1970's.

Comment: @BoPersson So it depends on the platform and the compiler

Comment: Read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: It's all about the platform. On some systems a signed char might be "unnatural" and slower than an unsigned.

Comment: @BoPersson Thx!

Comment: The text you quote is simply saying that `int` and `unsigned int` exist, etc.  `int` is always signed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from `char`, the signedness of the integral types is specified in the C and C++ standards, either explicitly, or by a simple corollary of the ranges that the types are required to implement.

The signedness of `char` is determined by the particular implementation of C and C++; i.e. it's typically up to the compiler. And the choice will be made to best suit the hardware.

Note that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are all *distinct* types, much in the same way that `int` and `long` are distinct types even if they have the same size and complementing scheme.

It's also not a particularly good idea to assign, for example,

```
numeric_limits<long>::min();
```

to an `int` value, the behaviour of this could be undefined. Why not use

```
auto foo = numeric_limits<whatever>::min();
```

instead?

Comment: @水飲み鳥: A long must be capable of representing -2<sup>32</sup> + 1

Comment: @水飲み鳥: Yes it is. What are you trying to say here, exactly? If a range includes negatives and positives then it must be a signed type. This is hardly rocket science.

Comment: Thanks for help! Also curious about the 0 and -1 for the `long` and `long long`. That could be a new question. However, I appreciate you could drop a line.

Comment: Do you think it has to do with the fact that what `numeric_limits<>` returns is being stored in an `int` ?

Comment: @水飲み鳥: Yes that's correct. Using `int` as the type is madness.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah, great. Thanks for the explanation!