# Using GetKeyState()

Tags: c++, winapi, keypress

I would like to have a boolean event toggle when a key is pressed. Specifically, the 's' key. I have been pointed to the function GetKeyState(), which supposedly works under the Win32 API. I understand the ASCII code for the letter 's' is 115, and so my code is as follows:

```
if (GetKeyState(115) == 1)
{
<EVENT>
}
```

However, this does not work. Why? Here is the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ... "If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled"

Comment: Just compare it to zero -> See : [How do I get the high- and low-order bits of a SHORT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302456/how-do-i-get-the-high-and-low-order-bits-of-a-short)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From what I understand you need to do:

```
if( GetKeyState(115) & 0x8000 )
{
    <EVENT>
}
```

The highest bit tells if key is pressed. The lowest tells if key is toggled (like, if caps lock is turned on).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but still my event doesn't occur when I press 's'. The program compiles just fine though. I'm using Win32 API, am I missing anything else? The compiler obviously recognises the function...

Comment: Maybe you want [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293). `GetKeyState` has to be called in response to keyboard event.

Comment: The virtual key codes for the letter keys correspond to the ASCII codes of the upper case letters. And you can even use a `char` instead of the `int` which makes the code more readable. So try `GetKeyState('S')`

Answer (score 15):

Since SHORT is signed, high-order bit equals sign bit.

Therefore to test if a given key is pressed, simply test if the value returned by `GetKeyState()` is negative:

```
if (GetKeyState('S') < 0) {
    // The S key is down.
} else {
    // The S key is up.
}
```

Besides, 115 is ASCII code for 's'. I believe, you should use capital case 83 to test the 'S' key.

Answer (score -3):

I use a global variable bool `altgr`

Example:

```
void Editor::HandleKey(char car) {

    bool shift = false;
    //bool altgr = false;
    bool printable = false;

    if (car == 27) SendMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);

    if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) == 1) shift = true;
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) == 0x8000) shift = true;
    // if(GetKeyState(VK_RMENU) & 0x80000000 == 0x80000000) altgr = true;
    if (car == 18) altgr = true;
```

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes you want to use a **combination of keys**.

To avoid the situations when a combination of keys (eg: VK_SHIFT && VK_LEFT)  satisfies two conditions:

```
std::cout << "Shift RIGHT pressed" << std::endl;
std::cout << "LEFT key pressed" << std::endl;
```

just use `Sleep(...);` and `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_...)`

[GetKeyState() vs. GetAsyncKeyState() vs. getch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770753/getkeystate-vs-getasynckeystate-vs-getch/17771038)

```
#include <windows.h>  

    ...

    while (1)
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000))
        {
            Sleep(200);
            std::cout << "Shift LEFT pressed" << std::endl;
        }

        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000))
        {
            Sleep(200);
            std::cout << "Shift RIGHT pressed" << std::endl;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
        {
            std::cout << "RIGHT key pressed" << std::endl;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
        {
            std::cout << "LEFT key pressed" << std::endl;
        }
   }
```

Comment: This seems rather unrelated to the OP's question.

Answer (score -11):

Bit late for this but the high order bit is 0x80000000 not 0x8000, change this and it will work fine.

The other bit - useful for nothing - it acts as if you pressed CAPS LOCK when you pressed LSHIFT.

Comment: As stated in [GetKeyState MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx), the return value is a `SHORT` (16 bits), not a 32 bit value (in other words, `0x80000000` is not valid).